# Putting in characters in a commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I am using the amscd package. I have the following commutative diagram code

```
\[
\begin{CD}
@.          @.                            @.                0\\
@.          @.                            @.                @VVV\\ 
@.          @.                            @.                M_\omega\otimes L\\
@.          @.                            @.                @VVV\\ 
@.          @.                            @.                L\otimes \Gamma(\omega)\\
@.          @.                            @.                @VVV {f}\\  
0@>>>M_L\otimes \omega@>>>\Gamma(L)\otimes \omega@>>> L\otimes \omega@>>>0\\
@. @. @. @VVV\\
@. @. @. 0
\end{CD}
\]
```

I want to write the letter "f" beside one of the vertical arrows, and also above one of the horizontal arrows. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: I guess you are using the `amscd` package. Remember, try to provide a MWE so others can help you more easily.

Comment: @Karlo- Thanks! I shall put that information in.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the letter 'f' beside one of the vertical arrows, and also above one of the horizontal arrows".

Comment: there is an example in the `amsmath` user's guide on p.21 that shows examples of notation on arrows like those you request.  `texdoc amsmath`.  (for"f" above a horizontal arrow, `@>f>>`, and beside a vertical arrow, `@VVfV`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is an example in the `amsmath` user's guide on p.21 that shows examples of notation on arrows like those you request: `texdoc amsmath`.

here is your diagram with the "f" applied to two arrows; i made a guess as to where you wanted them.  the braces around the "f" are not necessary, as it is only a single letter; a longer expression *would* require braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{CD}
@.          @.                            @.                0\\
@.          @.                            @.                @VVV\\ 
@.          @.                            @.                M_\omega\otimes L\\
@.          @.                            @.                @VVV\\ 
@.          @.                            @.                L\otimes \Gamma(\omega)\\
@.          @.                            @.                @VV{f}V {f}\\  
0@>>>M_L\otimes \omega@>>>\Gamma(L)\otimes \omega@>{f}>> L\otimes \omega@>>>0\\
@. @. @. @VVV\\
@. @. @. 0
\end{CD}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a spurious “f”

Comment: @egreg -- that "f" is in the original; didn't think it should be there, but left it because i wasn't sure.

Comment: @barbarabeeton- Thanks a lot! This was really helpful